# Adding an attribute to a M-M relation in Strapi

Tags: node.js, strapi

Suppose we have the following models:

1. student
2. exam

These two models have a many-to-many relation which normally in Strapi translates into a new separate relation table.

I want to specify the score of a student in a specific test.

Normally in plain SQL, this will mean adding a new column to the relation table that will add the score for each student-exam combination. But I don't know if Strapi has the flexibility to implement this approach.

My question is, Is there any possibility to achieve this using Strapi?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is multiple approaches possible:

1. by creating score collection with student and exam relation.
2. by creating a repeatable component in student, witch has score and exam.

Second option seems more appropriate since component would be bound to student.

Comment: Thanks a lot. We used the first approach with minor adjustments as it fits our case slightly better and it is working fine.